# JBoss dependency resolution issue with EJB?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ejb-3.0, application-server

I am using JBoss 4.x .

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-as-server</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could please let me know the equivalent dependency for 4.x version?

Thanks!

Comment: A google for "maven jboss 4.2.3" DID return results for me. Did you try it?

Comment: But it does not contain the same dependency..i looked at it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<groupId>jboss</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss</artifactId>
<version>4.2.3.GA</version>
```